# enableEcommerce: false for Enhanced Ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to know why my Purchases are not being stored in Google Analytics, the Preview of Google Tag Manager shows that I've enableEcommerce set to false, but as you can see I've this in Google Analytics Turned ON.

After following documentation, I've this dataLayer only in the thank you page:

[image]

As you can see:

1) I'm generating the products Array,
2) The tag is fired correctly.
**3) enableEcommerce : false**

Point 3 is what is not clear to me, because I've Ecommerce Enabled:

[image]

**enableEcommerce: false**

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Based on kgrr's answer, this is my current setup.

**event fires**

[image]

**dataLayer:**_

[image]

**dataLayer (first field name)**

[image]

**Google Analytics TAG Variable**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Not as conversion:

[image]

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of your Google Analytics settings variables, or relevant Google Analytics tag, which should send the purchase data? The enhanced ecommerce part would be relevant. Your product array seems to be wrong, but it's not clear, without seeing the tag settings.

Comment: @kgrg please, look at update 1 and tell me if I need to upload something else.

Comment: Thank you. Please try to make the recommended fixes, and let me know, if it works.

Comment: I saw a very similar behavior, as on your screenshots, and just had to a wait a bit after enabling ecommerce features in GA – it took at least half an hour for GA to start showing the relevant UI and data from GTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on all the details, you have shared, there a few errors, that you should fix, to get your purchase tracking working.

**Your tracking ID is incorrect.** You can provide a tracking ID either by adding it directly as a Tracking ID, or adding it as part of a Google Analytics Setting variable. (Where it will be provided similarly as Tracking ID). At the moment, you pass your Google Analytcs Settings variable into the tracking ID field. As you have already prepared this type of variable, I suggest to use it in its proper place, but remove tracking ID provided from the Google Analytics tag. The only setting to be overwritten, is the enhanced ecommerce setting. (As it seems from the images.)

**Your purchase object is not following the enhanced ecommerce format.** Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases), the `products` array is part of the `purchase` object. At the moment, they are siblings in your code, so GTM won't be able to process, and append it to the event.

**Your product objects are not following the enhanced ecommerce format.** At the moment, you are not using the proper keys in your product objects, so GTM won't be able to pass this data to Google Analytics. [This is a general reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data) about the product data, and this is a [working example](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases), how various attributes are passed to GTM. You should fix the key-value pairs to match the format requested by GTM.

**Update:**
Also, you must ensure, that enhanced ecommerce feature is enabled in your Universal Analytics tag or your Google Analytics Settings variable. If it's not enabled, GTM ignores this data.

Comment: may you expand on why my tracking ID is not correct? The Tracking ID in the property setting is: `UA-134628373-1`, and that is what is on the Variable. On the other hand I see the statements about the product objects must be changed as you suggest, I'm working on that. Thank you.

Comment: stickers_galito_id is not a tracking ID itself, but a whole group of Google Analytics settings. You need to use it in the proper setting field, not as tracking id. See: https://i.imgur.com/lK3x7hw.png

Comment: I've made your recomendations but cannot see the transactions on GA Ecommerce panel (0 revenue). May you checkout my new screenshoots? ty

Comment: Can you see the Ecoomerce/Purchase event in realtime or daily reports?